# Highlight the label with in the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-collection

I am new in tikz,I am manually create an image,In that figure coloured part shows that highlight the label how I do this by tikz I am using the following code for the label, How alter this code.

```
    \documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage{
            calc,
            graphicx,
            eso-pic,
            tikz,
            }



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \draw (2.1,8) rectangle (6,4);
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,4)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-1};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,5)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-2};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,6)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-3};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,7)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-4};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,8)[rotate=0,color=black] {label-5};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) showing how you got your graph. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: It's rather hard for me to understand what you actually want to do. Are you after `\node [transform shape,rotate=0,color=black,fill=black!10]  (Label) at (0,0) {0};`, so the background of the node is filled with gray?

Comment: @ Andrew and Torbjørn T. I am crete this figure using photoshop, for understanding purpose I am include this figure and now I am update the code and In that  code contains 5 labels I want to highlight labels like in figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `color=black` option, and apply a style to each node via `every node/.style=`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx,eso-pic,tikz,}

\tikzset{My Node Style/.style={draw=pink, fill=pink, fill opacity=0.50, text opacity=1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1,
  every node/.style={My Node Style}
  ]
    \draw (2.1,8) rectangle (6,4);
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,4) {label-1};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,5) {label-2};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,6) {label-3};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,7) {label-4};
    \node [transform shape] (Label) at (1.5,8) {label-5};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```